# Including White Space in a Path, Powershell

Tags: svn, powershell

I am interfacing Powershell to Subversion, and I am having an issue, where Powershell is not completeling my url for Subversion, due to a space being in the path.

```
$Source = C:\Users\'+env:USERNAME+'\Desktop\FileDownloadLocation'
$SVNPath = 'http://subversion/svn/MainDirectory/SecondaryDirectory/Directory with a Space/subdirectory/finalLocation'

TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /url:$SVNPath /path:$Source /closeend:2
```

What shows up in the Subversion Checkout Window is:

```
'http://subversion/svn/MainDirectory/SecondaryDirectory/Directory '
```

I need to pass the remaining portion of the URL to Subversion.  Is there a way for me to do this in Powershell, and how would I have to go about including whitespaces into my URL Paths for Subversion, in Powershell?

Comment: After talking to a buddy of mine, he pointed me towards adding a %20 instead of the space.  Subversion will see this as a 

    'http://subversion/svn/MainDirectory/SecondaryDirectory/Directory%20with%20a%20Space/subdirectory/finalLocation' 

which will look strange, but then it will download the correct file/path of files.  So anybody else whom might run into this issue with Powershell, %20 instead of a ' ' worked for me and subversion.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old, but perhaps this will help someone else. The underlying issue can come up with many command line arguments, not just with TortoiseProc.exe.

For some reason the %20 idea was not working for me so here is an alternative solution. The issue here is that TortoiseProc.exe (among many others) requires that a path with spaces in it be surrounded by quotes.  But by default PowerShell does not pass the actual quote characters, only what is inside them.

The solution: include escaped quotes inside the "normal" quotes.  So it would look like this:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /url:"`"$SVNPath`"" /path:"`"$Source`"" /closeend:2
```

Pay close attention to the backtick characters that are "escaping" the inner quotes.  This causes those quote characters to be passed literally as part of the string and now TortoiseProc.exe will properly handle file paths and URLs with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just enclose the variable in quotes as well.

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /url:"$SVNPath" /path:"$Source" /closeend:2
```

Comment: I just gave that a quick try, but it unfortunately does not seem to work that way.  It still cuts off at the Space.  However, as in the comment I left on my original post creating the directory with '%20' in place of ' ' will actually work.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

enclosing the path in triple quotes worked for me:

```
$path="""path to folder/file with spaces"""
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:$path /closeend:1
```